# vb.net string split with a rule

Tags: vb.net, string, split

I have 2 strings and i want to use the `String.Split()` Method on them, what i want to do if the string contained "Love You" is to ignore the space and save it in the Array as one Element However if it contained "Love" alone the save it normally

```
str1 = "I Love Her"
str2 = "I Love You Not"


'no problem with splitting the first string
Dim strsplit1() As String = str1.Split(New String() {" "}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

For the second string..how can i ignore the space splitter and save "Love You" as one element?

note this is just an example, my mind telling me check the indexofLove+1 but how can i get the index of Love?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use simple trick here.
Before splitting the string replace "Love You" with "Love_You", and after splitting is done, scan received array and replace "Love_You" back to "Love you".

Comment: You can even improve this solution (in case you have real "Love_You" string in your data). Replace "Love You" with "Love" & ChrW(17) & "You", because ChrW(17) is definitely not text symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me

```
 Dim strsplit2() As String = str2.Split(New String() {" "}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    Dim loveindex = Array.IndexOf(strsplit2, "Love")
    If strsplit2(loveindex + 1) = "You" Then
        strsplit2(loveindex) = "Love You"
    End If
```

i don't care about the rest because all i want is to check if strsplit2(loveindex) exists in a predefined ArrayList

so

```
  For Each x As String In strsplit2
        If myarraylist.Contains(x) Then
            MsgBox(x)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

i am sorry for not mentioning it, but your solution is good for anyone who cares about the rest of the array.

My problem was that there are 2 groups one called "Holmegaard" and one called "Holmegaard Lamps" these are contained in product names and i had to parse them only to show the right image to each one of them